# how to merge same way in svn as git does?

Tags: svn

I don't understand completely what is going on this crappy legacy software.
i've tried to `svn copy svn://trunk svn://branch/name` still missing files in some directories. I've tried `svn merge -rxxx:yyy svn://branch/name` being in trunk dir, revision changed, no files were added in branch that's still present in trunk.

What's going on?? How to merge in a git-way? just clone god damned files from one dir to another and that's it.. does `svn merge` means something different??

question is how to do the same in svn???:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge hotfix
```

one big minus that i have nested trunk/branch repository in here.. maybe this spoils all the picture?

Comment: Take a deep breath and relax. If you think a piece of software is crappy because you need to read the manual, why do you like git? Your description is too vague (why attempt `copy` if you want to merge? what error message do you get? what does "nested trunk/branch repository" mean?). I suggest you edit the question and try to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ svn merge ^/branch/name
```

or with -r but into your working copy. I guess you can not merge from svn:// to svn:// directly. After merge, just commit

```
merge: Merge changes into a working copy.
usage: 1. merge SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]
(the 'sync' merge)
2. merge [-c M[,N...] | -r N:M ...] SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]
(the 'cherry-pick' merge)
3. merge --reintegrate SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]
(the 'reintegrate' merge)
4. merge SOURCE1[@N] SOURCE2[@M] [TARGET_WCPATH]
(the '2-URL' merge)
```

every option need TARGET_WCPATH

Answer (score 1):

SVN doesn't merge in the git way -- it merges in the svn way.  Part of this is simply because git grew up solving a similar problem but in a very different environment.  Part is that subversion doesn't support the concept of "multiple ancestors" so all subversion operations act like a git rebase.

Unless you do extra work, SVN merges act like git merges that are entirely squashed.  The git argument is that it's better to expose the changesets during the merge.

In order to make it easy on myself doing more git like merges I wrote a tool (in bash) some time ago to help my merge in subversion preserving individual changesets.  This is late alpha quality code but has been useful in several organizations:  https://github.com/dmsasser/svntools.  This tool works on Linux and cygwin.

After you run this tool the result is equivalent to a "git rebase".